# How to draw this cartesian graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was wondering how would I draw this graph using LaTeX and its tikz packages for my math class. [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a simple cartesian plane system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202037/how-to-generate-a-simple-cartesian-plane-system)

Comment: welcome and have alook at the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.80]
    \tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=8,xmin=-8,ymin=-8]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
%    \draw[ very thick,dashed,latex-latex] (-6,4) -- (6,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!