# How to draw a cartesian plane like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, intersections

I read some topics but I still don't know how to draw this cartesian plane, someone could help? My difficulty is how to draw the intersection.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have a formula for g(x)?

Comment: Thanks! Could be a general formula like this one: 
3*sin(\x)+ln(\x)-3.5*ln(\x)+2 ; 
domain x = 2, y = 4

Comment: It's most likely be faster/easier to compute the coordinate of the intersection in e.g. Python/other programming language, then put the coordinate in. TikZ has I think intersections library, but there are some numerical issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a simple cartesian plane system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202037/how-to-generate-a-simple-cartesian-plane-system)

Comment: Im very grateful to everyone! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(11,11)
\psset{arrowinset=0.12, plotpoints=200, algebraic, linejoin=1}
\psaxes[showorigin=false, ticksize=-3pt 3pt,labels=none, ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(10,10)[$ x $, -140][$ y $, -130]
\pnodes(-1,-1){A}(9,9){B}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{A}{B}\naput[nrot=:U, npos=0.8]{$y=x$}
\psplot[linewidth=2pt, linecolor=RoyalBlue]{0.5}{4}{4*sin(x)-2*ln(x)+4}
\rput{-75}(2.7,5){$y = g(x)$}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](2.9,0)(2.9,2.9)(0,2.9)
\uput[d](2.9,0){$x'$}\uput[l](0,2.9){$x'$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard, this is perfect. thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Comment: Bernard, how do i change the scale?

Comment: The scale of the graph?  You can write at the very beginning `\psset{unit=some length}`  (the default is 1cm).

Comment: Gotcha!! Thankss!

Comment: Sorry, Bernard, promise it's the last time. Is it possible to put a caption?

Comment: You can manually add a legend,but if you want a real caption (referenceable), the best to save the result as a .pdf file and insert it in a figure environment with a caption, via `\includegraphics`

Comment: Got it done! Im very grateful for your time.

Comment: If you are an Emacs user, you can get the abscissa of the intersection from the `quick-calc (Cx * q)` command with the argument `root(4 * sin(x) - 2 * ln(x)+ 4=x, x, 3)_1`. 3 is the initial value of the iterative calculation. `root` returns a vector whose first coordinate is the root, so `_1` is the desired resul

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package, which is based on `TikZ`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,font=\scriptsize]
% \tzhelplines(5,5)
\tzaxes(-.2,-.2)(5,5){$x$}[b]{$y$}[l]
\tzfn[dashed,thick]"line"{\x}[-.2:5]{$y=x$}[l]
\tzplotcurve[blue,thick]"curve"(.5,4.3)(1,4.2)(2.5,4.1)(4,.5){$y=g(x)$}[45]; % [ar] also works in version 2.0
% intersection and projection
\tzXpoint*{line}{curve}(X)
\tzproj(X){$x^*$}{$y^*$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [ar] option gives an error on line 11. I have to insert it in with the other options.(tzplot.sty 2021/03/20 v1.0.1, pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)

Comment: @gigiair I changed [ar] to [45]. But if you update `tzplot` to version 2.0, both [ar] and [45] will work.